# How to write unit tests for Auth0 rules

Tags: node.js, npm, auth0

I have multiple rules in my tenant and now I want to write unit tests for my rules just like https://github.com/auth0/rules/tree/master/test Now the issue is in the docs (https://auth0.com/docs/support/testing) it’s written that we can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-rules-testharness module for unit test our rules but I think the explanation is old and it’s not updated because in the sample project (https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-rules-testharness-sample) we need to add webtask token and sandbox url and now we can’t find webtask token in Auth0 dashboard (https://manage.auth0.com/#/account/webtasks) and also where can I get this sandbox url? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that npm package is a little out of date.  Here are some updated resources:

Unit testing rules

Rules Best Practices:  https://auth0.com/docs/best-practices/rules
Specifically: https://auth0.com/docs/best-practices/rules#testing

Some example repos:
https://github.com/auth0-customers/rule-test-example
https://github.com/auth0/auth0-rules-local-testharness